# AJAX Loading in Child Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, accordion

I'm having trouble explaining this but here it goes:

I have a custom accordion script that's triggered when a user clicks on a link. There are multiple accordions on each page, each with there their own link. This script works perfectly, each link only opening its correct accordion.

Now, I need to modify this script to load content via AJAX in to a div within the accordion. I have the  AJAX loading down, but instead of loading in to one DIV, it's loading in to every DIV with the same class. I understand why it's doing this, but I don't see how to tie it in with the existing script. It uses the same button to load the content, so it should be fairly easy.

The accordion script uses the `data-target` attribute to specify which accordion to open, so that should be able to be tied in to the new script, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML link:

```
<a class="button maximize accordionHeading" data-target="firstAccordion" href="/Load/?ID=1">More Info</a>
```

HTML div:

```
<div class="accordionHidden firstAccordion">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="six columns">
            <img class="load-image" src="images/dirt.jpg" />
        </div><!--/.six.columns-->
        <div class="six columns load-description">
            <!-- this is where the content should be loading -->
        </div><!--/.six.columns-->
    </div><!--/.row-->
</div><!--/.accordionHidden firstAccordion-->
```

Script:

```
$("a.accordionHeading").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("."+$(this).data("target")).slideToggle();
    $(this).addClass("minimize");
    if ($(this).text() == "More Info") {
       $(this).text("Less Info");
       $(this).removeClass("maximize").addClass("minimize");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("maximize").removeClass("minimize").text("More Info");
    }

    // this is what I'm trying to add.
    var $loadID = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".load-description").load($loadID);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `data-target` of the anchors you can select the target divs by their class names, Try the following:

```
var $loadID = $(this).attr("href");
var tgt = $(this).data('target')
$("." + tgt + " .load-description").load($loadID);
```